# css overflow visible - hidden part of a page

Tags: css, overflow

I am struggling with common problem - after clicking on anchor link leading to a section of the same page, a whole block gets moved to the top a few pixels, causing to hide other part of page. On [this particular page](http://www.biome.sk/aktivator-rastu-mihalnic-revita-eps), after clicking on reviews link (right to the fivestar) and returning to the top of a page, the page title (above breadcrumbs) gets lost.

I have learned that this is caused by a rule `overflow: hidden`. I found that it can be fixed by applying rule `overflow:visible` on `div#content-inner.content-inner.block`. But no matter what I do, this rule is allways overriden by `simple .block { overflow:hidden }`

Can anybody help me please?

Comment: Have you tried using `!important` to override the `overflow:hidden`?

Comment: Dont just !important it. Find a reason why you need important first. Put your more general rule before the div#content-inner.content-inner.block (so this one override the hidden value)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure which style sheet you are putting in your css but I know the .block is in style

try

```
#content-region-inner .block {
    overflow: visible;
}
```

If this don't work please tell me which css you are using to put this in

Comment: It should be in "local" stylesheet. I put there what you suggested - not working.

Comment: @user1031742 try putting it at the end of the file instead of start of file.

Answer (score 1):

Change the `overflow:visible` rule to `overflow:visible !important`. :)

Comment: grzegorz: I'd love to put more general rule but any solution I tried get's overriden by simple .block rule. Adding overflow:visible to that div in chrome editor directly on page works well. But putting that same div as a rule into stylesheet doesn't. Realy don't know why

Comment: That's odd.. If it's added to the style-sheet, does it show up in the Chrome 'Inspect Element' window?

Comment: well, when put into chrome inspect element window directly, it is working. When put into stylesheet, it is overriden. I'm confused that is why I ask here:)